# c++ scanf causes SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, scanf

when i try to assign values to dynamic array using function scanf, i'll get this error "Signal received: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)" after first assign, but when I use cin, it works and all values are assigned correctly. Why? Is the problem in my code?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int r = 5;

short* pole[r];


for(int x = 0;x<r;x++){
    pole[x] = new short[r];
    for(int y = 0;y<r;y++){
        scanf("%d",pole[x][y]); //error
        //cin >> pole[x][y]; //OK
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an ampersand, and the `%d` should be `%hd` (for `short int`):

```
scanf("%hd",&pole[x][y]);
```

Your original version was passing the *value* of `pole[x][y]`, whereas `scanf()` expects a *pointer*. Also, the type specifier (`%d`) was wrong for the type of `&pole[x][y]`.

Comment: oh thanks :x i thought it was not necessary as it is array element

Comment: @user1145902: The reason C++ user like the stream version is the type safety. The compiler checks the type of what you are reading into and make sure to use the correct code. Using a format specifier is very error prone (brittle). if you get the wrong type (or the type of the object is changed) the code will break very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
scanf("%d",&pole[x][y]);
```

as **scanf()** expect the address of a variable to write to.

Also note that you're using a number of shorts but you're reading integers. Use %hd instead.

Answer (score 1):

In case you wonder why it compiles at all, it is because scanf is totally non-typesafe as after the first argument it takes a variable parameter list (...).

This means you can pass in anything you want and it will just "hope for the best" that it is what you wanted.

It should be a pointer but it will roll 4 or 8 bytes off the stack and whatever is in it will be treated as a pointer and it will try to read from it.

Given that this is C++ (you used new not malloc) may I suggest you use the C++ library and not use scanf. Use vector preferably rather than arrays. Use a matrix class if you want a matrix, and you can use iostream or similar to perform input data reads.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you are getting a segmentation fault. `scanf()` asks you for the pointer to the variable, you are passing the value.

```
scanf("%d",&pole[x][y]);
```